# while loop does not acknowledge if statement

Tags: python, web-scraping, while-loop

Building a web scraper, to get lucky draws from a lottery site and using `while` loop for it to check for all the values that I need and adding an if statement to have a `break` point. So this is the code wrote:

```
numbers = []
N = 7
page_still_valid = True
archive = 1

while page_still_valid:
    page_url = f'https://perlas.lt/lt/statistic/eurojackpot?tab=archive&Filter%5BdrawFrom%5D=1&Filter%5BdrawTo%5D={archive}#archive'
    res = requests.get(page_url)
    
    if 'Žaidimas nr. ' + str(archive) not in res.text:
        page_still_valid = False
        
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    for item in soup.select('.number'):
        numbers.append(item.text)

    archive=archive+1 
    subList = [numbers[n:n+N] for n in range(0, len(numbers), N)]
```

So added the subList for numbers to be arranged in the same way like on the website and when i check subList, it is full of duplicate values. I am not sure if the loop gets my `if` statement where to break and have no clue why is it giving me duplicate values.

```
lucky_numbers = []
N = 7
lottery_url = requests.get('https://perlas.lt/lt/statistic/eurojackpot?tab=stats&Filter%5BdrawFrom%5D=1&Filter%5BdrawTo%5D=437#archive')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(lottery_url.text, 'lxml')
csv_file = open('eurojackpot.csv', mode='w', newline='')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')

for item in soup.select('.number'):
    lucky_numbers.append(item.text)

subList = [lucky_numbers[n:n + N] for n in range(0, len(lucky_numbers), N)]

csv_writer.writerows(subList)
csv_file.close()
```

I can get the values with a `for` loop, but I have to to input the url manually.

Problems:

1. Duplicate values from while loop
2. If statement doesn't break

I hope i provided enough info to understand

Comment: "If statement doesn't break" indicates that the condition `'Žaidimas nr. ' + str(archive) not in res.text` has always been `False`

Comment: You're using `drawFrom=1` every time through the loop, only changing `drawTo`. So each page includes all the results from the previous page, and you get duplicates.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Any idea how tow write the if for the break to be valid?

Comment: Actualy, made it work. Thank you